# Jquery mobile hide "spinner" by default in loadingmessage

Tags: ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

By default, jquery mobile displays a "spinner" in the loadingmessage that is displayed when a page is loading.

When I manually show the loadingmessage, I can type this:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "No spinner", true);
```

where the third argument is boolean "textonly" which disables the spinner on true.

What I want to accomplish is to disable the spinner by default for all page changes (where the loadingmessage is displayed while loading). The only properties I can configure on initializing the jquery mobile framework are

```
loadingMessage (string, default: "loading")
loadingMessageTextVisible (boolean, default: false)
loadingMessageTheme (string, default: "a")
```

Is there any way to disable the spinner by default?

Sources:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the bottom of your page as a workaround for hiding the spinner:

```
<style>
.ui-icon-loading {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ah, this could work. Not the best solution I was hoping for, but until they make something to apply this "textonly" boolean, this is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
.ui-loading .ui-loader
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Wow, without the burden of the spin animation the transition is much smoother.